# WSO2ESB The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

Referring following Link

http://wso2.com/library/articles/2012/10/implementing-restful-services-wso2-esb/

and Tried to call
`http ://localhost:8280/students/001`

Got following Error Message

The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is `http ://localhost:9783/services/StudentService` and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.

I am using WSO2ESB 4.8.1 and DSS 3.2.1.

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Solved by Converting Message Content Format from SOAP 1.1 to SOAP1.2.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you were able to locate a solution by converting the message content format from SOAP 1.1 to Soap 1.2.

Since these are old servers I hope you've had a chance to upgrade to the latests.